# Get the exact value from android getprop

Tags: android, bash, parsing, grep, adb

I wish to get specific value of properties from adb command getprop

To get specific value I use:

```
adb shell getprop ro.product.display_name
adb shell getprop ro.bootloader
adb shell getprop ro.serialno
adb shell getprop ro.product.model
```

Result example:

```
Galaxy Watch5
RFT4JD6GHK
RGHJKABVGTS
SM-R860
```

But this is not good, cos for each value, I need to do getprop each time. I wish to ask it once per device and then parse the result to get values.

Something like:

```
adb shell getprop
```

and then what I get from stdout is long list with all properties and values

```
...
[ro.build.version.release]: [4.2.2]
[ro.product.display_name]: [Galaxy Watch5]
[ro.bootloader]: [RFT4JD6GHK]
[ro.hardware]: [qcom]
[ro.opengles.version]: [196108]
[ro.product.brand]: [Verizon]
[ro.product.manufacturer]: [samsung]
[ro.serialno]: [RGHJKABVGTS]
[ro.product.model]: [SM-R860]
...
```

How to parse this big list end get same result as separate commands? I try bellow but I get the whole thing with brackets:

```
adb shell getprop | grep "ro.product.display_name\|ro.bootloader\|ro.serialno\|ro.product.model"
```

Result:

```
[ro.product.display_name]: [Galaxy Watch5]
[ro.bootloader]: [RFT4JD6GHK]
[ro.serialno]: [RGHJKABVGTS]
[ro.product.model]: [SM-R860]
```

Comment: Why do you limit yourself to bash commands? IMHO if you want to get multiple values in an efficient way you better use a script language like Python that has built-in commands for string manipulation, regex and so on.

Comment: I need to use bash, cos this is just a part of a very big shell script. Anyway is there solution to use regex or some parsing to get pure values from above?

Answer (score 1):

I solve it, but I'm not sure if there is easier solution:

```
adb shell getprop | grep 'ro.product.display_name\|ro.bootloader\|ro.serialno\|ro.product.model' | cut -d ":" -f 2 | sed 's:^..\(.*\).$:\1:'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk` and defining an array with the keys you want (`ro.product.display_name` used as an example here), you can do

```
adb shell getprop | awk -F '[][:]' 'BEGIN {keys["ro.product.display_name"]++} $2 in keys {print $5}'
```